# How can I get the current user email (instead of the user ID) in this shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, typeform

We want to display the user email instead of the user ID using this code in wordpress as we are trying to link this to typeform.

https://www.cozmoslabs.com/docs/profile-builder-2/developers-knowledge-base/shortcodes/current-user-link-shortcode/

Comment: using an external resource to represent code is no better than a picture. Please go through the help https://stackoverflow.com/help and also read my link above. Code should go directly in your question. Stackoverflow has a pretty good code highlighter engine in place.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) OR [`get_userdata($user_id)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) to get user's email address.